# FParsec backtracking in nested parser

Tags: f#, fparsec

I want to parse expressions that are constructed like: `a is x or y or z or b is z or w`, so basically I have the same separator for different rules in my grammar.

I already succeed parsing such expressions with Antlr since it can backtrack quite nicely. But now I want to parse it with FParsec and I don't get the inner parser to not be greedy. My current parsers look like this:

```
let variable = // matches a,b,c,...

// variables ::= variable { "or" variable }+ ;
let variables =
    variable .>>? keyword "or" .>>.? (sepBy1 variable (keyword "or"))

let operation =
    variable .>>? keyword "is" .>>.? variables

// expression ::= operation { "or" operation }+ ;
let expression =
    operation .>>? keyword "or" .>>.? (sepBy1 variable (keyword "or"))
```

In my example the variables parser consumes `x or y or z or b` and the whole thing fails at `is`. This means I need to make that `variables` parser less greedy or make it backtrack correctly.

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45653927/fparsec-backtracking-sepby) where they make a backtracking version of `sepBy1`, but using that still does not solve my problem. I guess that is because I want to backtrack into a nested parser.

So what is the correct way to make FParsec accept my input?

Comment: I feel like the root cause of your issue is that the keyword `or` has two different meanings. If I'm parsing your example expression correctly, you want it to parse like `(a is (x or y or z)) or (b is (z or w))`, right? So the same keyword `or` means "Alternatives for a single `is` match" and also means "Either of these expressions could be true". If you switched your "Alternatives for a single `is` match" to be something else, like `|` for example, then you might have less difficulty. I've also come up with another idea, which I'll write in an answer since it's rather long.

Answer (score 0):

Besides switching one of the meanings of `or` to `|` as I mentioned in a comment, you could also use `notFollowedBy (keyword "is")` as follows:

```
let variables =
    variable .>>? keyword "or" .>>.? (sepBy1 (variable .>> (notFollowedBy (keyword "is"))) (keyword "or"))
```

I'm not really enthusiastic about this solution because it doesn't generalize easily. Are there other keywords besides `is` that could appear after a variable? E.g., do you have a syntax like `b matches x or y`, or anything similar? If so, then you'd need to write something like `(notFollowedBy ((keyword "is") <|> (keyword "matches")))` and it can quickly get complicated. But as long as the keyword `is` is the only one that is throwing off your parser, using `(notFollowedBy (keyword "is"))` is probably your best bet.